# Don't know why this code works (use alternative dictionary class with __missing__ method)

Tags: python, python-3.2

this question arises when i read the book "Python cookbook" by  David Beazley, Brian K. Jones, in page 61, 62. I summarize:

```
>>> s = '{name} has {n} messages.'
>>> name = 'Guido'
>>> n = 37
```

Now, if just want to replace {name}, but don't want to replace {n}, define an alternative dictionary class with a `__missing__()` method

```
>>> class safesub(dict):
        def __missing__(self, key):
            return '{' + key + '}'
```

then

```
>>> del n     # Make sure n is undefined
>>> s.format_map(safesub(vars()))
```

you get the desired result:

```
'Guido has {n} messages.'
```

my question:
why need `__missing__()` method to make this code work?

Comment: Why not try it *without* the `__missing__` method? Or look at the [`dict[key]` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) which explains what `__missing__` *does*.

Comment: Looking at the [`str.format_map()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) might also help. Note that it has an example that's very similar to what you've read in the cookbook. There's one subtle difference though—can you spot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format_map()` will look in its argument for the key `'n'`. Because this key is *missing*, it would raise a `KeyError` in a normal `dict`. Defining the `__missing__` method determines what happens here instead: `'{n}'` is returned so that the formatted string remains the same.